# AppleScript to mount and unmount drives

Tags: macos, hard-drive, ssd, shutdown, applescript

this is my first post on this site, so excuse me if this is a double post but I couldn't find anything similar.

I'm on Macbook Pro 13 early 2011, I have installed an ssd and moved the hdd to the optibay, made a clean install of Yosemite, my second hdd is a 1TB where I store my work and data before making a backup when I'm home.

I don't need the hdd to be mounted at all time and I need to save energy and keep it hided, so I removed it from spotlight search, did "sudo pmset -a disksleep 1" and created two applescript, one to be launched at login to directly unmount the hdd and the second one is launched via the eject key that I modified with karabiner (previously known as KeyRemap4MacBook)

The second script launches a dialog that asks for a password then asks if I would like to access the hdd, if yes, the hdd will be mounted, if no, it will be unmounted

The problem is, that I noticed, that if I shut down my macbook while the hdd is mounted, the disk identifier changes for the hdd changes from disk2 to disk1 and both scripts will try to unmount the ssd, so I need to manually eject the hdd and restart so everything goes back to normal.

What I want to do, is to modify the script that launches via the eject key to make it launch a first dialog, exactly like the shut down dialog, 
removing the cancel button and adding a button called "Expansion" (which is the name of the hdd).

I'm a newbie with applescript, So here's what I want to do :
[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ViF2q.jpg)

If Restart is pressed, then unmount the hdd and restart
If Sleep is pressed, then unmount the hdd and sleep
If shutdown is pressed, then unmount the hdd and shutdown
If Expansion is pressed, then launch the old script

Here's my old script, the new script should come just before it

```
     set my_password to display dialog ¬
    "Allow access to Expansion" with title ¬
    "Expansion" with icon caution ¬
    default answer ¬
    "" buttons {"Cancel", "OK"} default button 2 ¬
    giving up after 295 ¬
    with hidden answer
if text returned of my_password is "password here" then

    set answer to the button returned of (display dialog "Allow access to Expansion?" with icon caution buttons {"Yes", "No"})

    if answer = "Yes" then
        do shell script "diskutil mountDisk disk2"
        tell application "Notifications Scripting"


            display notification "Expansion" subtitle "is now mounted" sound name "Blow"

        end tell
    else if answer = "No" then
        try

            do shell script "hdiutil eject disk2"

        on error

            tell application "System Events"
                set termOpen to count (processes whose name is "Terminal")
                set amOpen to count (processes whose name is "Activity Monitor")
            end tell


            tell application "Terminal"
                activate
                set newTab to do script "lsof /Volumes/'HFS HD'"
            end tell

            tell application "Activity Monitor"
                activate
            end tell

            delay 3

            set question to display dialog "Kill running?" buttons {"Yes", "No"} default button 2
            set answer to button returned of question

            if answer is equal to "Yes" then
                do shell script "lsof -P | grep '/Volumes/HFS HD'  | awk '{print $2}' | xargs kill -9"
                do shell script "hdiutil eject disk2"
            end if


            tell application "Activity Monitor"
                if amOpen is 0 then
                    quit
                end if
            end tell

            tell application "Terminal"
                if termOpen is 0 then
                    quit
                else
                    close (first window whose selected tab is newTab) saving no
                end if
            end tell



        end try
        tell application "Notifications Scripting"


            display notification "Expansion" subtitle "is now unmounted" sound name "Blow"

        end tell
    end if
else
    tell application "Notifications Scripting"


        display notification "A Goomba killed Mario!" subtitle "Next time, try jumping on it" sound name "Sosumi"

    end tell
    quit

end if
```

Thank you for your help, and sorry if TLDR :p

Comment: Thanks for answering your own question! I removed the "solved" from your title; please see http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/01/accept-your-own-answers/ Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, after 3 hours of googling and trying, I found a solution.

Mounting and Unmounting the hdd with "diskutil mountDisk disk2" and "hdiutil eject disk2" was a BAD IDEA, because I figured out that the disk identifier keeps changing randomly no matter if the hdd was unmounted or not in the last shutdown, so the script I was trying to add was useless.

The solution I found was obviously the UUID, at the beginning I couldn't get it to work correctly but after multiple attempts, everything works fine.

How to: 
Launch Disk Utility, on the left you'll see each disk with their partitions
Select the partition you want to create the script for, and clic Info on top left, an info window will pop up, make sure that's the correct partition, in the info list, you'll find ( Universal Unique Identifier : Bunch-of-letters-and-numbers-here )
That's the UUID

My final script :

```
set answer to the button returned of (display dialog “Mount the second HDD?” with icon caution buttons {"Yes", "No"})

if answer = "Yes" then
    do shell script "diskutil mount *YOUR UUID WITHOUT THE ASTERISK* ”

else if answer = "No" then
    try

        do shell script "diskutil unmount *YOUR UUID WITHOUT THE ASTERISK*"

    end try
end if
```

The command Try is to avoid showing a message if the disk is already unmounted.

That's it, Simple and accurate, hope this helps in the future